# Secure FTP connection on Windows

Tags: php, openssl, xampp, sftp, php-openssl

The official php documentation says:

> "ftp_ssl_connect() is only available if both the ftp module and the OpenSSL support is built statically into php, this means that on Windows this function will be undefined in the official PHP builds"

Is there any way to use this function with xampp anyway, or do you know any other windows php solution with static OpenSSL?

Comment: Ftp_SSL_connect (as clearly stated in the manual) does NOT do Secure FTP (file transfer protocol in an SSH tunnel) it implements FTPS (FTP  in a TLS tunnel)

Comment: @symcbean note that SFTP is not "Secure FTP" but "SSH File Transfer Protocol" (the name is misleading since it's not a "transfer" protocol but anyway).

Comment: The sad thing is using TLS with FTP is optional, so the bad guy will always be able to force a downgrade attack by swallowing the `STARTTLS` command (or whatever the FTP equivalent is). Switch to VPN or SSH instead.

Comment: If you want the answer to your second question (non-blocking SFTP), you need to ask a separate question. You cannot ask two completely different questions in a single post. This is Q&A site, not a discussion forum.